I can't get Future to complete with a value
A value of type Object? can't be returned from the method getUser because it has a return type of Future\<UserModel\>.
  Future<UserModel> getUser(String userId) async {
    QuerySnapshot userDoc = await _usersCollectionRef.where('userId', isEqualTo: userId).get();
    print('user doc: ${userDoc.docs[0].data()}'); //user doc: Instance of 'UserModel'
    return userDoc.docs[0].data();
  }

Why won't the future complete even though there clearly is a UserModel inside the return.
EDİT
Thank you all for the replies. Here is the code or _usersCollectionRef
  FirestoreDatabase() {
_folderCollectionRef = _firestore.collection(FOLDERS_COLLECTON_REF).withConverter<FolderModel>(
    fromFirestore: (snapshots, _) => FolderModel.fromJson(
      snapshots.data()!,
    ),
    toFirestore: (folderModel, _) => folderModel.toJson());

_usersCollectionRef = _firestore.collection(USERS_COLLECTION_REF).withConverter<UserModel>(
    fromFirestore: (snapshots, _) => UserModel.fromJson(
      snapshots.data()!,
    ),
    toFirestore: (userModel, _) => userModel.toJson());}

Also here is the code for fromJsonin my UserModel:
UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json)
  : this(
nickName: json['nickName']! as String,
userId: json['userId']! as String,
email: json['email']! as String,
role: json['role']! as String);

EDİT
I seem to have solved the problem. I don't know if this is a good solution, but I would still appreciate feedback as to what was wrong in the first place for the sake of learning:)
  Future<UserModel> getUser(String userId) async {
QuerySnapshot userDoc = await _usersCollectionRef.where('userId', isEqualTo: userId).get();
return userDoc.docs[0].data() as UserModel;}


Please add the declaration of _usersCollectionRef to you code. Possibly it is missing a type parameter.

Your userDoc object is an object of type QuerySnapshot. When you call .docs[0] the type of object that is returned is QueryDocumentSnapshot. When you further call data(), the type of object that is returned is T, which is a generic type object. So it's not an instance of UserModel but a Map that contains key-value pairs.
If you want to convert that data into an object of the UserModel class, then you have to create a fromMap() function method as explained in the answer from the following post:

Firestore data into a Model class


Thank you for the great explanation, makes sence. But I already have a 'fromJson()' function (I put it at the end of the question). When I tried to add a 'fromMap()' function the same problem arose.

What happens when you convert userDoc.docs[0].data() to an object of type UserModel?

I think the last bit I edited in does that, and it solves the problem but I am still confused as to what was wrong in the first place

I was about to write you simply to cast the userDoc.docs[0].data() as UserModel. I'm glad you edited your question. I have also edited my answer.

Did my answer/ comment help? Can I help you with other information?

Yes, thank very much. I'd upvote it but I don't have the reputation:)

QuerySnapshot is a generic class QuerySnapshot<T extends Object?>.
In your declaration of userDoc you omitted the type parameter:
QuerySnapshot userDoc = await _usersCollectionRef.where(
  'userId', isEqualTo: userId,
).get();

That's why T defaults to Object? and userDoc.docs[0].data() is assumed to return an object of type T.
The analyzer does not know that the runtimetype of userDoc.docs[0].data() will be UserModel.

Example with correct type parameters:
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class UserModel {
  UserModel({required this.name, required this.id});
  final String name;
  final int id;

  factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json) {
    if (json case {'name': String name, 'id': int id}) {
      return UserModel(name: name, id: id);
    } else {
      throw UnsupportedError('Could not convert $json to UserModel.');
    }
  }

  Map<String, Object?> toJson() => {'name': name, 'id': id};
}

// usersRef is an instance of CollectionReference<UserModel>
final CollectionReference<UserModel> usersRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('Sample_Path_User_Model')
    .withConverter<UserModel>(
      fromFirestore: (snapshots, _) => UserModel.fromJson(snapshots.data()!),
      toFirestore: (movie, _) => movie.toJson(),
    );

Future<UserModel> getUser(String userId) async {
  QuerySnapshot<UserModel> userDoc =
      await usersRef.where('userId', isEqualTo: userId).get();

  return userDoc.docs[0].data();
}



So, how does the OP apply this to fix their code? Could you add the corrected code?

I  would suggest  declaring userDoc explicitly as a QuerySnapshot<UserModel> and checking that the same type parameter was used when creating the CollectionReference.

When I do this I get the error: A value of type 'QuerySnapshot<Object?>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'QuerySnapshot'.

I can't reproduce the error. The fact that you have to cast an Object? to UserModel is an indication that somewhere a type parameter is missing. You have not shown where you declared: _usersCollectionRef. Is it CollectionReference _usersCollectionRef?
